# How to check if an object has a rotation in a range near the rotation of another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not very experienced in unity C# so this may be something that is very easy that I'm over complicating.

what I'm trying to achieve is to get a variable to set to something depending on if 2 objects have similar rotations, but its outputting bullet1 every time.

```
if(hand1.transform.rotation.y > (hand2.transform.rotation.y + 90) 
   && hand1.transform.rotation.y < (hand2.transform.rotation.y - 90))
{
    bulletresult = bullet1;
}
else
{
    bulletresult = bullet2;
}
```

Comment: The condition looks like it can never be true so I'm even more surprised that you would end up with bullet1.
If hand1.transform.rotation.y is greater than (hand2.transform.rotation.y + 90)
then hand1.transform.rotation.y cannot also be less than (hand2.transform.rotation.y - 90).
Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `hand1.tranfsform.rotation.eulerAngles.y` instead of `hand1.tranfsform.rotation.y`. Same of course for `hand2`

Answer (score 0):

You can you the function float Angle(Quaternion a, Quaternion b) to find out the angle between to rotation.
And please check your condition again. It will never be true. (Tell me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

[`Transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) is a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) (see also [Wikipedia - Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion))!

**Except you know exactly what you are doing - which you don't, no offense ;) - **NEVER** directly get or set the individual components of a `Quaternion`!**

So in case you didn't know: A `Quaternion` has not `3` but **`4`** components `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`**. All of them move in the range `-1` to `1`.

Your condition can **never** be true.

---

You *could* check using [`Quaternion.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html)

```
if(Quaternion.Angle(hand1.transform.rotation, hand2.transform.rotation) <= 90)
```

**but** be aware that this returns the rotation delta on **any** axis.

---

Alternatively for getting the delta **only on the global Y-Axis** you could rather use vectors and flatten the individual right (local X) or forward (local Z) vectors onto the XZ plane and use [`Vector3.Angle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html)

```
// get the local right vectors in global space
var right1 = hand1.transform.right;
var right2 = hand2.transform.right;

// flatten the vectors so we don't have any difference in the global Y axis
right1.y = 0;
right2.y = 0;

// Now get the angle between these
if(Vector3.Angle(right1, right2) < 90)
```